# Sql Server, how can I identify a result column so I can use it in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the problem.

```
select count(studentID) AS count from educators where count  > 1 group by studentid
```

Will not work as SQL Server does not yet know about the count column.

So I have to do this

```
select *
  from (select count(StudentID) as count
          from educators
         group by studentid
       ) s
 where s.count > 1
```

Is there a more elegant solution?  It seems like there should be a much nicer way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jonathan, I really do need to look over this stuff before I post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `HAVING` clause, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT StudentID, COUNT(StudentID)
FROM educators
GROUP BY StudentID
HAVING COUNT(StudentID) > 1
```

The query will display all StudentIDs that appear more than once.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(studentID) AS count 
FROM educators 
GROUP by studentid 
HAVING COUNT(studentID) > 1
```

HAVING is like a where for aggregate functions. So it works on AVG, SUM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(StudentID)
FROM
   educators
GROUP BY
  studentid
HAVING
  COUNT(StudentID) > 1
```

Learn your tools and a clipboard developer you shall not be.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is about as good as it gets.  You could try using a name other than `count` for the alias, but it probably won't help much. The column aliases are nominally only for use in the result set and sometimes (some DBMS allow it in) the ORDER BY clause.

Additionally, conditions on aggregates belong in the HAVING clause after the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(studentID) AS count
  FROM educators
 GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(StudentID) > 1
```

Obviously, in the nested SELECT case, you can apply the condition in the WHERE clause of the outer query, but not in the WHERE clause of the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(studentID) AS count
FROM educators
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(StudentID) > 1

Always remember that when you are using aggregate function like min(),max(),count(),avg() you need to used having clause.